# SMTPRecipientsRefused at /accounts/signup/ django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

When I'm using django all-auth i'm facing error somethings like this.
{'test@gmail.com': (553, b'5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user ....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntCd2.png)

With out django allauth it is working fine.

Here is my configurations

1

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.domain_naame.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'sandeep@domain_name.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'account_password'
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally searching here and there i found solution i.e i need to add DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting in django settings file